# Is it a correct way to write a moment generating function?

Tags: probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

When I write the moment generating functions, can I write $M_{aX}(t)$ instead of $M_{X}(at)$ ?

Thank you really much!

Comment: It would convenient for you if you used MathJax instead of uploading an image. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

I mean, it's true that $$M_{aX}(t) = \mathbb E[e^{(aX)t}] = \mathbb E[e^{atX}] = M_X(at).$$
This is a special case of the more general rule for linear combinations: if $S = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i$, where the $X_i$ are independent random variables, then $$M_S(t) = \prod_{i=1}^n M_{X_i}(a_i t).$$
I guess there's connotations that, writing $M_{aX}(t)$ as opposed to $M_X(at)$, you care about the distribution of $aX$ as opposed to the distribution of $X$. But either is equally mathematically valid.

...If you wanted to be really weird, you could write $M_X(t) = M_{tX}(1)$, but nobody does that.

Comment: thank you really much! this really helps